# Are there any open source word processors made with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, open-source

If you know of one, I'd love to learn about it.

Thanks, as always -- Al C.

Answer (score 4):

not exactly word processor but perhaps can fit well http://www.trichview.com/

Comment: Very good component that you can use to build your own word processor, but its not open source.  Its a library you can purchase source too and use royalty free.

Comment: +1 for TRichView, great components and very good support from Sergey.

Answer (score 1):

The other major player is [WPTools](http://www.wpcubed.com).

It's not open source, but I'm pretty sure there isn't an open source word processor in Delphi, unless it wraps the built-in TRichEdit. Sorry!